# Getting GridBagConstraints from a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I have a panel that generates from a document.  I don't know exactly how many fields and labels I'll be adding, and I want it to make two columns of label and field.  How I think I can do this is with GridBagLayout and getting the GridBagConstraints, but I can't figure out how to do that.  Anyone know how to get the GridBagConstraints back out of a JPanel/JFrame?

If not, any alternatives you can suggest would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a panel that generates from a document. I don't know exactly
>   how many fields and labels I'll be adding, and I want it to make two
>   columns of label and field. How I think I can do this is with
>   GridBagLayout and getting the GridBagConstraints, but I can't figure
>   out how to do that. Anyone know how to get the GridBagConstraints back
>   out of a JPanel/JFrame?

- you would need to loop inside Components added to container
- take currenet layout to the temporary variable (I assumned there are JLabels and JTextFields placed into JPanel)

e.g.

```
Component[] comps = panel.getComponents();
GridBagLayout layout =  (GridBagLayout) panel.getLayout();

for (int i = 0; i < comps.length; ++i) {
    Component comp = comps[i];
    GridBagConstraints gbc = layout.getConstraints(comp);
    System.out.println("Component : " + comp + " , with GBC: " + gbc);
}
```

- then very simple, similar way is possible to remove some JComponent from Container and replace with a new...

> any alternatives you can suggest would be greatly appreciated.

- use [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for variable amount of columns and rows

Comment: Two things I would like to change in this snippet. __Firstly__ bring this `GridBagLayout layout =  (GridBagLayout) panel.getLayout();` out of the for loop and __Secondly__ use an enhanced for loop (for (Component comp : comps)) +!, though for the rest :-)

Comment: @nIcE cOw first is good point, second is nicer, but I'm love for loop,

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick.  To let you know, I just picked the last component, used it to feed me it's location, and then calculated where to put the next one in the JPanel from it's GridBagConstraints.  Seems like common sense, but I wanted to share just the same.

Comment: @CodeDragonDM seems like as you complicating simple things, is possible, but container.add(myComponent) add a new JCOmponents to the end, its has last, may index in ZOrder